# Apply CSS style conditionally when specific product category is in Woocommerce cart

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Before I start my question I would like to let you know that I am a graphic designer, not a developer. I am helping out a buddy with their website so please forgive my ignorance and lack of knowledge.

I am building a site in Wordpress with a WooCommerce shop. I am fairly comfortable with CSS and HTML but have virtually no php knowledge and I am very new to WooCommerce.

I've got a very specific thing I'd like to achieve but I don't really know where to start.

Essentially I'd like to apply a conditional css style once a product of a particular category is placed in the cart (and reversed if the product is removed). Specifically I'd like to change the colour of an icon that sits in a widget and will be displayed on the header. So the effect is that when a visitor adds a 'gift' to their cart, the 'gift' icon will 'light up' to prompt the visitor to next add a 'card' and so on.

I found the following which looks at first glance like it might get me close, but I don't know how to implement it, so any help would be very appreciated:

```
// set our flag to be false until we find a product in that category
$cat_check = false;

// check each cart item for our category
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

$product = $cart_item['data'];

// replace 'membership' with your category's slug
if ( has_term( 'membership', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
    $cat_check = true;
    // break because we only need one "true" to matter here
    break;
}
}

// if a product in the cart is in our category, do something
if ( $cat_check ) {
// we have the category, do what we want
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following slightly different revisited code instead in a hooked function, that will allow you to add some inline CSS styles when a specific product category is found in cart items:

```
add_action( 'wp_head' , 'custom_conditional_css_styles' );
function custom_conditional_css_styles(){
    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) return; // We exit is cart is empty

    // HERE your product category
    $product_category = 'membership';
    $found            = false;

    // Loop through cart items checking for our product category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( has_term( 'membership', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $found = true;
            break; // Found we stop the loop
        }
    }

    if ( ! $found ) return; // If the product category is noy found we exit 

    // Here come your CSS styles
    ?>
    <style>
        .my-class { color:red;}
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> When using `has_term()` with cart items, never use `$cart_item['data']->get_id()` but always `$cart_item['product_id']` instead.

Comment: You don't need to paste the function multiple times as it works all the time and so it's need to be only one time in your function.php file. You can have in this same function, multiple conditions and styles instead.

Comment: I do have one more thing I'd like help with - is there a way to make the above happen without requiring a page reload (possibly with ajax?) Thanks again, I am so grateful for the help!

Comment: @DaveClarke I imagine that is possible, but Ajax driven code is much more complicated and advanced.

Comment: OK thanks, I suspected as much - I have just gone with a workaround for now of making sure the page reloads after an item is added. Thanks again for your help today, I am very grateful. If there's any way I can buy you a beer I'd be glad to!

Answer (score 0):

suppose we have two categories in product that time one category have product_cat-slippers class and second category have product_cat-floaters.

you can apply css with :not selector view in below code.

```
:not(.product_cat-floaters) {
    color: red;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp